# VSCode not launching debugger (opening terminal)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, launch

Been using VSCode for quite some time.
Working fine for pre 1.69.1 builds but now, myself, and others, cannot launch a Python app or run pytest.

I actually have about 6 dozen entries in my launcher.json file.  Tried a few and they all don't work anymore.

Using python 3.6.8

Recommendations?

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of what is showing in your VS Code when you click the debugging option?

Comment: There is nothing on the screen to show.  Also no logs
But, must have gotten some updates, after several reinstalls, and other work, and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Found issue
New Python - IntelliSense package from Microsoft does not support Python 3.6.x
Upgraded to newer python and things work.
Now need to upgrade the product.